# AWS IoT button certificates

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, iot

We have 500 AWS buttons and building an iOS app to configure them.

1) Do we need a different certificate for each button? The documentation suggests that there is a limit of 10 certificates per account. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_RegisterCACertificate.html

Also, the Configure process also requires a private key. Not sure how we generate that with the documentation above.

2) Can we use the same certificate and private key, bundle it with the iOS app and upload it to the button during the configuration? If yes, where can we find more information about how to do this? We tried this approach without success with a certificate we created here:
https://console.aws.amazon.com/iotv2/home?region=us-east-1#/certificatehub

Our team is a bit lost on how to achieve our goal, and having a hard time finding answers in the documentation (configure AWS button via app). Does anyone know how Amazon does it with their iOS app?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit of 10 CA certificates. These certificates are used to create and sign device certificates. They are not given to devices. The limit of 10 should be plenty as you only need one CA certificate. The CA private key comes from the vendor that you purchased the CA from. For the device private key, then link below shows how to download that.

You can use the same certificate for IOT devices, but AWS strong recommends against this. You should use a different device certificate for each device.

This link will provide details on creating and activating a device certificate:

[Create and Activate a Device Certificate](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/create-device-certificate.html)

[Attach a Certificate to a Thing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/attach-cert-thing.html)